# PyInstaller + Wine + NLTK = WinError 127 "RtlIpv6AddressToStringA". Any ideas?

Tags: python, nltk, ipv6, wine

### The issue

I developed a PyQt app that uses NLTK to throw item recommendations based on a query, and now I need to package it into a standalone app. After checking the internet for weeks, I tried fbs, but ended up going to pyinstaller. When I tweaked the necessary things, the app was succesfully built... **For Linux**. Issue here is, I need it to be able to run on Windows, and I'm using Ubuntu.

In order to package it for Windows, I read everywhere that the best choice is to just wine pyinstaller and call it a day, but when I do that, I end up with this error message:

```
OSError [WinError 127] Procedure not found: 'RtlIpv6AddressToStringA'
```

For what I can collect, this is a semi-usual thing, since it looks like NLTK and PyInstaller do not get along well.

### What I tried

- Modifying hook-nltk.py and changed the lines regarding nltk_data
- Using PyInstaller with the .py file as well as the .spec file
- Looking pretty much everywhere finding someone with a similar problem, to no avail

Comment: Usually you need to make sure to build the exe on at least the same or older Windows version which you are planning to run it. That means a built made on Win10 isn't guaranteed to run on Win7.

Comment: That's good to know, since I have no idea what's the kind of Windows machine it'll be running on, but I don't see how this relates to the OSError problem. I'm building it on an Ubuntu system using wine.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ip2string/nf-ip2string-rtlipv6addresstostringa, it depends on `ntdll.dll`, I interpret the error message like the DLL was found, but the function is not there ?! Probably you need to check if the DLL is added to the build and/or include the version from Wine into your build.

Comment: Right now, as far as I'm concerned, this `ntdll.dll` is present on Wine's `drive_c/windows/system32` as well as in `drive_c/windows/systemwow64`. I don't know if you're talking about this or specifically in the project folder. Anyhow, it **is* there, so I'm guessing it's not that?

Comment: Which of them is added to the exe ? Possibly it's just a 32/64bit issue ...

Comment: You're probably using an old version of Wine that doesn't have RtlIpv6AddressToStringA. Try again with the latest version.